# Identifying string and column names passed as arguments via ellipses in R

Tags: r, ellipsis

I have been using ellipses in R to pass arguments to a function
the arguments are typically in the format (col1,filter1,col2,filter2...) passed via function call as

`df <- function_x(treaty_id,"abc",country,"usa")`

please note that the column names are not passed under double quotes only the filters are.

```
 function_x <- function(...){
      
      colnam1 <- enquo(..1)
      filter1 <-  (..2)
      colnam2 <- enquo(..3)
      filter2 <-  (..4)
      
if(filter1 == "usa")
{

 if(quo_name(colname1) == "treaty_id")
    { then do something}
}
```

The problem is i dont think the first if condition on filter1 is not working in R. Also can you please suggest if treatment of second if condition is correct.

I have been really struggling with it so thanks in advance.

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solution. Requiring these odd parameter sequence orders isn't very idiomatic in R. There may be better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more direct for your ellipses to support named arguments such as `function_x(treaty_id="abc", country="usa")`, etc. Lacking context of how you expect to be able to use this, I'd think it'd be more idiomatic and flexible (e.g., multiple uses of the same name works fine, `function_x(aa=1, aa=c(2,5))`. There are likely other options here, but perhaps some context and intended use from you would make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The treatment of your `if` statements is technically correct. You can use `rlang::enquo` to capture the quosure and then use `rlang::quo_name` to return the object name or expression as string. You can use this string in the `if` clause to trigger different actions.

```r
library(rlang)

function_x <- function(...){
  
  colnam1 <- enquo(..1)
  filter1 <- (..2)
  colnam2 <- enquo(..3)
  filter2 <- (..4)
  
  if (filter1 == "abc") {
    print("do one thing here")
  if (quo_name(colnam1) == "treaty_id") {
    print("and do something here")
    }
  }
}

function_x(treaty_id,"abc",country,"usa")
#> [1] "do one thing here"
#> [1] "and do something here"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>